# Matlab: Subplot for 2 rows and 10 columns

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How can I plot 20 images in one plot with 2 rows and 10 columns in matlab? I know I have to use

> subplot()

function. But I am confused regarding the parameters to be given.

I tried giving

> subplot(2,10,row_index,col_index)

but it doesn't seem to work.Please help.

Comment: "[`subplot(m,n,p)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html): divides the current figure into an m-by-n grid and creates an axes in the grid position specified by p. ... If p is a positive integer, then subplot creates a new axes in grid location p." So `p` is a scalar (linear index) specifying the subplot number.

Answer (score 5):

The first two arguments of the `subplot` function give the total number of rows and columns of subplots in the figure, respectively, and the third gives the row-wise *linear index* of the current subplot. If you want a 2x10 matrix of images, they will be numbered like this:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

So, for instance, the second one over, third one down can be set using `subplot(2,10,6)`.

You are not limited to putting a single image/axis on a single subplot. If you wanted to span an axis across the top two columns, you would use `subplot(2,10,[1 2])` and the axis would stretch to fill both spots.

Comment: Good explanation of the linear indexing issue. I think that was the source of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.  The index is just into the total number of subplots.

```
figure
for i=1:20
   subplot(2,10,i);
   plot((1:10).^i)
end
```